# Serializing/Deserializing an object that is derived from Java.Lang.Object throws exception (using System.Text.Json)

Tags: xamarin.android, system.text.json, .net-7.0

In one of my **.net7-android** project, I am trying to serialize an object using **System.Text.Json**. My object is derived from **Java.Lang.Object**. I am not intrested in serializing/deserializing the base class (Java.Lang.Object).

The exception I am getting is "**Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported.**". Anyone has any ideas how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the public properties declared by [`Java.Lang.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.object?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) must (directly or indirectly) return an object of type `System.Type`, thereby causing the exception.  Since you don't want to serialize any of these properties anyway, you could create a custom [`JsonTypeInfo` modifier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#modifying-json-contracts) that excludes all properties declared by `Java.Lang.Object`.

First, define the following extension methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> IgnorePropertiesDeclaredBy(Type declaringType)
        => (Action<JsonTypeInfo>) (typeInfo => 
                                   {
                                       if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object || !declaringType.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
                                           return;
                                       foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                                           if (property.GetDeclaringType() == declaringType)
                                               property.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => false;
                                   });
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> IgnorePropertiesDeclaredBy<TDeclaringType>() => IgnorePropertiesDeclaredBy(typeof(TDeclaringType));
    public static Type? GetDeclaringType(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.DeclaringType;
}
```

And now you can use `JsonExtensions.IgnorePropertiesDeclaredBy<Java.Lang.Object>()` to omit all properties declared by `Java.Lang.Object` when serializing instances of derived types like so:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.IgnorePropertiesDeclaredBy<Java.Lang.Object>() },
    },
    // Add other options as required
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase, 
    WriteIndented = true,           
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myJavaObject, options);
```

Note that this will only suppress properties declared by some base type.  Suppressing properties declared by an interface that the type implements is not implemented.

Demo fiddle using a mockup of `Java.Lang.Object` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vNQS6.